# Serialising an Enum member to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization, enums

How do I serialise a Python `Enum` member to JSON, so that I can deserialise the resulting JSON back into a Python object?

For example, this code:

```py
from enum import Enum    
import json

class Status(Enum):
    success = 0

json.dumps(Status.success)
```

results in the error:

```
TypeError: <Status.success: 0> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you want to encode an arbitrary `enum.Enum` member to JSON and then decode
it as the same enum member (rather than simply the enum member's `value` attribute), you can do so by writing a custom [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) class, and a decoding function to pass as the `object_hook` argument to [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) or [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
PUBLIC_ENUMS = {
    'Status': Status,
    # ...
}

class EnumEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if type(obj) in PUBLIC_ENUMS.values():
            return {"__enum__": str(obj)}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def as_enum(d):
    if "__enum__" in d:
        name, member = d["__enum__"].split(".")
        return getattr(PUBLIC_ENUMS[name], member)
    else:
        return d
```

The `as_enum` function relies on the JSON having been encoded using `EnumEncoder`, or something which behaves identically to it.

The restriction to members of `PUBLIC_ENUMS` is necessary to avoid a maliciously crafted text being used to, for example, trick calling code into saving private information (e.g. a secret key used by the application) to an unrelated database field, from where it could then be exposed (see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35999686#35999686).

Example usage:

```
>>> data = {
...     "action": "frobnicate",
...     "status": Status.success
... }
>>> text = json.dumps(data, cls=EnumEncoder)
>>> text
'{"status": {"__enum__": "Status.success"}, "action": "frobnicate"}'
>>> json.loads(text, object_hook=as_enum)
{'status': <Status.success: 0>, 'action': 'frobnicate'}
```

Comment: If you have your code in a module(enumencoder.py, for example), you must import the class that you parse from JSON to dict. For example, in this case, you must import the class *Status* in the module enumencoder.py.

Comment: My concern was not about malicious calling code, but malicious requests to a web server. As you mentioned, the private data could be exposed in a response, or it could be used to manipulate code flow. Thank you for updating your answer. It would be even better if the main code example was secure though.

Comment: @JaredDeckard my apologies, you were right, and I was wrong. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for your input! This has been educational (and chastening).

Comment: would this option be more appropriate `if isinstance(obj, Enum):` ?

Comment: Is there a way to somehow 'annotate' the enum with the encoder class so that the encoder is used by default?

Comment: values() does not exist and without it "unsupported operand type(s) for 'in': 'EnumType' and 'EnumType'"

Comment: @JohnGlen `PUBLIC_ENUMS` must be a dictionary, as shown in the code in the answer. Your error message seems to indicate that you've accidentally made it an Enum instead.

Comment: Ah, yes. I am thinking of making custom hooks so I can use the enums.

Answer (score 302):

I know this is old but I feel this will help people. I just went through this exact problem and discovered if you're using string enums, declaring your enums as a subclass of `str` works well for almost all situations:

```
import json
from enum import Enum

class LogLevel(str, Enum):
    DEBUG = 'DEBUG'
    INFO = 'INFO'

print(LogLevel.DEBUG)
print(json.dumps(LogLevel.DEBUG))
print(json.loads('"DEBUG"'))
print(LogLevel('DEBUG'))
```

Will output:

```
LogLevel.DEBUG
"DEBUG"
DEBUG
LogLevel.DEBUG
```

As you can see, loading the JSON outputs the string `DEBUG` but it is easily castable back into a LogLevel object. A good option if you don't want to create a custom JSONEncoder.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I am mostly against multiple inheritances, that's pretty neat and that's the way I am going with. No extra encoder needed :)

Comment: @madjardi, can you elaborate on the problem you are having? I have never had a problem with the value of the string being different than the name of the attribute in the enum. Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: `class LogLevel(str, Enum):
    DEBUG = 'Дебаг'
    INFO = 'Инфо'`
in this case `enum with str` no work properly (

Comment: You can also do this trick with other base types, for example (I don't know how to format this in the comments, but the gist is clear: "class Shapes(int, Enum): square=1 circle=2" works great w/o need for an encoder. Thanks, this is a great approach!

Comment: This str mixin can have unintended side effects: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339635/how-to-deserialise-enumeration-with-string-representation).

Comment: Side effects fixed in JSONS 1.6.1

Answer (score 117):

The correct answer depends on what you intend to do with the serialized version.

If you are going to unserialize back into Python, see [Zero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24482806/208880).

If your serialized version is going to another language then you probably want to use an `IntEnum` instead, which is automatically serialized as the corresponding integer:

```
from enum import IntEnum
import json

class Status(IntEnum):
    success = 0
    failure = 1

json.dumps(Status.success)
```

and this returns:

```
'0'
```

Comment: I like to  unserialize back into Python

Comment: In python3.2, This doesn't actually return what the answer says.  I get: `>>> json.dumps(Status.success)`  -> `'Status.success'`

Comment: @AShelly: The question was tagged with `Python3.4`, and this answer is 3.4+ specific.

Comment: Perfect. If you Enum is a string, you would use `EnumMeta` instead of `IntEnum`

Comment: @bholagabbar: No, you would use `Enum`, possibly with a `str` mixin -- `class MyStrEnum(str, Enum): ...`

Comment: I used `EnumMeta` and the json serialises and deserialises perfectly.

Comment: @bholagabbar, interesting.  You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I would avoid inheriting directly from `EnumMeta`, which was intended as a metaclass only. Instead, note that the implementation of `IntEnum` [is a one-liner](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/enum.py#L670) and you can achieve the same for `str` with `class StrEnum(str, Enum): ...`.

Comment: Wow! That and the `str` mixin cover most cases I'll ever need!

Answer (score 41):

In Python >= 3.7, can just use
`json.dumps(enum_obj, default=str)`

If you want to use the enum value, you can do

`json.dumps(enum_obj, default=lambda x: x.value)`

or if you want to use the enum name,

`json.dumps(enum_obj, default=lambda x: x.name)`

Comment: Looks nice but it will write the `name` of enum into the json string. The better way will be to use `value` of the enum.

Comment: Enum value can be used by `json.dumps(enum_obj, default=lambda x: x.value)`

Comment: However, this would not work if an Enum is used as a key. It would still complain of "TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None" - Most of the solutions above do not take care of the usage as key. Enum is supposed to be hashable.

Answer (score 35):

You just need to inherit from `str` or `int` class:

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique            
class StatusEnum(int, Enum):
    pending: int = 11                                      
    approved: int = 15                                       
    declined: int = 266
```

That's it, it will be serialised using any JSON encoder.

Comment: Note that this serializes to the enum value, in string form, e.g. "11" or "15".

Comment: This saved me a ton of time, thanks...

Answer (score 15):

I liked Zero Piraeus' answer, but modified it slightly for working with the API for Amazon Web Services (AWS) known as Boto.

```
class EnumEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Enum):
            return obj.name
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

I then added this method to my data model:

```
    def ToJson(self) -> str:
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, cls=EnumEncoder, indent=1, sort_keys=True)
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Why do you need to add `ToJson` to your data model?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `jsonpickle` the easiest way should look as below.

```py
from enum import Enum
import jsonpickle


@jsonpickle.handlers.register(Enum, base=True)
class EnumHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):

    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        return obj.value  # Convert to json friendly format


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Status(Enum):
        success = 0
        error = 1

    class SimpleClass:
        pass

    simple_class = SimpleClass()
    simple_class.status = Status.success

    json = jsonpickle.encode(simple_class, unpicklable=False)
    print(json)
```

After Json serialization you will have as expected `{"status": 0}` instead of

```
{"status": {"__objclass__": {"py/type": "__main__.Status"}, "_name_": "success", "_value_": 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even combine the solutions mentioned above with the automatic value creation for Enums. I use this in combination with Pydantic and FastAPI to provide lower case names for a REST API:

```
from enum import Enum, auto
import json

class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    pass

# this creates nice lowercase and JSON serializable names
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values
class AutoNameLower(StrEnum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name.lower()

class AutoNameLowerStrEnum(AutoNameLower):
    pass

class MyActualEnum(AutoNameLowerStrEnum):
    THIS = auto()
    THAT = auto()
    FOO = auto()
    BAR = auto()

print(MyActualEnum.THIS)
print(json.dumps(MyActualEnum.THIS))
print(list(MyActualEnum))
```

Console:

```
>>> MyActualEnum.THIS
>>> "this"
>>> [<MyActualEnum.THIS: 'this'>, <MyActualEnum.THAT: 'that'>, <MyActualEnum.FOO: 'foo'>, <MyActualEnum.BAR: 'bar'>]
```

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me:

```
class Status(Enum):
    success = 0

    def __json__(self):
        return self.value
```

Didn't have to change anything else. Obviously, you'll only get the value out of this and will need to do some other work if you want to convert the serialized value back into the enum later.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) describing that magic method.  Are you using some other JSON library, or do you have a custom `JSONEncoder` somewhere?

Comment: Possibly this user is importing simplejson?