# Python 2.7 IntEnum: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-2.7, enums

I want to use IntEnum in my project and i have to serialize enum value into json and then deserialize it back.

The problem is when i use python 2.7 i get this error:
`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

When i use python 3.* all is ok.

The code is (for python 2.7):

```
import json
from enum import IntEnum

class DigitEnum(IntEnum):
    A = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print DigitEnum.A
    a = json.dumps(DigitEnum.A)
    print a # DigitEnum.A
    a = json.loads(a) # error here
    print a
    print a == DigitEnum.A
```

python 3.*:

```
import json
from enum import IntEnum

class DigitEnum(IntEnum):
    A = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(DigitEnum.A)
    a = json.dumps(DigitEnum.A)
    print(a) # 1
    a = json.loads(a)
    print(a)
    print(a == DigitEnum.A)
```

Is it possible to avoid creating custom JSONDecoder\JSONEncoder for my enum class or the only way is to use something like this:

```
a = json.dumps(DigitEnum.A.value)
```

The primary goal is to save compatibility between to major python versions

Comment: how do you want to *save compatibility between to major python versions* if you have 2 different snippets for 2 versions? afaik you can leave **Python 3** version (with parentheses around `print` arguments) and it will work in **Python 2.7** as well

Comment: The line causing the issue is `a = json.loads(a)`.It's caused by the fact that `a` is not a JSON object, so it can not be decoded.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, this is the main question. I need the way to use json for my enum class in both major python versions. This enum package, as i know, was created specially for this purpose: save compatibility. I need only enum value when i deconding enum, so, it is ok if i lose all info about enum class

Comment: @chromaerror, so, is it possible to force json to use enum value, not a enum name for serialization without custom json encoder\decoder?

Comment: As far as I am aware, no. You should be using a custom JSON encoder. You can take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481852/serialising-an-enum-member-to-json

Comment: @chromaerror, thank you, i saw this question, but in my case i use IntEnum and the behaviour of this class is different in serialization. 
When i use Enum i will get this error in both python versions as also said in related question. But if i use IntEnum i will get this error only in python 2.7.
This is strange for me, but maybe i miss something crucial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.5+ `json` was modified to work properly with `IntEnum` so that, for example:

```
json.dumps(DigitEnum.A) == 1
```

This change was not backported to 2.7 (and won't be) so the corresponding code in 2.7 results in:

```
json.dumps(DigitEnum.A) == 'DigitEnum.A'
```

which is a `str`, not a `DigitEnum` and not an `int`.

---

Side note:  *always use `repr()` when debugging so you can see what the actual types/values are*.