# What are the caveats of inheriting from both str and Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, multiple-inheritance

What are the caveats (if any) of using a class that inherits from both `str` and `Enum`?

This was listed as a possible way to solve the problem of 
[Serialising an Enum member to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481852/serialising-an-enum-member-to-json/51976841#51976841)

```
from enum import Enum

class LogLevel(str, Enum):
    DEBUG = 'DEBUG'
    INFO = 'INFO'
```

Of course the point is to use this class as an enum, with all its advantages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When inheriting from `str`, or any other type, the resulting enum members are also that type.  This means:

- they have all the methods of that type
- they can be used as that type
- and, most importantly, they will compare with other instances of that type

That last point is the most important: because `LogLevel.DEBUG` is a `str` it will compare with other strings -- which is good -- but will also compare with other `str`-based `Enum`s -- which could be bad.

[Info regarding subclassing enum from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others)

Comment: If the comparison is done as if they were strings there i guess that there will also be a slow down?

Comment: @Alonme: Not enough to worry about.