# Modify Enum to return value by default

Tags: python, recursion, enums, metaclass

I am trying to modify Enum to return value by default:

```
class EnumDirectValueMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __getattribute__(cls, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(cls, name).value
        except AttributeError:
            return object.__getattribute__(cls, name)

class Currency(Enum, metaclass=EnumDirectValueMeta):
    USD = "USD"
    EUR = "EUR"
    GBP = "GBP"
```

So that I don't need to call `Currency.USD.value`, but only need to call `Currency.USD` to return `"USD"` (by default).

However, I always get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Tried also modifying `__get__` instead to `return self.value` or `return str(self.value)`, etc. same thing happens. I can't seem to find a way around getting into recursion.

Is there an elegant solution to this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Even though `print(Currency.USD)` prints string `USD` there are other issues.

Iterating trough Currency items with `[ccy for ccy in Currency if ...]`
returns `[Currency.USD, Currency.EUR, Currency.GBP]`
not the `['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP']` as it was intended.
Now these list comprehensions are not so numerous and I can go around this with `[ccy.value for ccy in Currency if ...]` but seems like bad practice.

In Debug mode, I can see the `ccy` has value `Currency.USD` and trying to get `balance[ccy]` gives eror `KeyError: <Currency.USD: 'USD'>`

Seems to me basically the same as `balance[Currency.USD]` but that one works perfectly, as does `balance['USD']`, both returning the expected value.

Comment: With the code you provided, `print(Currency.USD)` prints string `USD`.

Comment: code working fine, `Currency.USD` giving `USD` , cannot reproduce the error

Comment: Added additional info in the edit!

Comment: So do you get RecursionError or not? Please bring your question to a consistent state without conflicting information. (Don't write "Edit:", we can see the edit history.)

Comment: Not really a solution, but I guess you could use str(ccy) instead of ccy.value

Comment: What's the point of using `Enum` in this case? Just make `Currency.USD` a normal attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `Enum` and `str` to get what you want.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60728807/208880) for details.