Difference of Enums in python
I was exploring different fields in Tortoise ORM and found out about CharEnumField which accepts a string enum for it to work. In the docs author used this class:
class Currency(str, Enum):
    HUF = "HUF"
    EUR = "EUR"
    USD = "USD"

It works. But then I wondered what if I remove str and inherit only from Enum:
class Currency(Enum):
    HUF = "HUF"
    EUR = "EUR"
    USD = "USD"

Surprisingly, both cases worked fine. However, tortoise has another type of enum field - IntEnumField which (according to docs) accepts IntEnums:
class Status(IntEnum):
    offline = 1
    online = 2
    unknown = 3

In this case I cannot use regular Enum class. It is strictly required to use IntEnum otherwise it throws a really long error.
This got me wondering, what is the difference of all those enums? Why IntEnum exists and StrEnum don't? Why can't we just inherit from Enum and be good to go?
Here's the code of a model, if anyone would want to reproduce:
class User(Model):
    id = BigIntField(primary_key=True)
    currency = CharEnumField(Currency, default=Currency.USD)
    test = IntEnumField(Status, default=Status.unknown)


"Why IntEnum exists and StrEnum don't?" Actually, it does in Python 3.11+: enum.StrEnum. "Why can't we just inherit from Enum and be good to go?" I think this is well covered in the documentation: IntEnum is the same as Enum, but its members are also integers and can be used anywhere that an integer can be used. Is there a particular part of the explanation that doesn't quite make sense to you?

What is the difference between inheriting and not inheriting from str as I did in code block #1 and #2?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60727103/11082165
