# How to use enum value in asdict function from dataclasses module

Tags: python, enums, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass with a field `template` of type Enum. When using the `asdict` function it converts my dataclass to a dictionary. Is it possible to use the [`value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) attribute of `FoobarEnum` to return the string value instead of the Enum object?

My initial idea was to use the [`dict_factory=dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) parameter of the `asdict` function and provide my own factory but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from enum import Enum


@dataclass
class Foobar:
  name: str
  template: "FoobarEnum"


class FoobarEnum(Enum):
  FIRST = "foobar"
  SECOND = "baz"


foobar = Foobar(name="John", template=FoobarEnum.FIRST)

print(asdict(foobar))
```

Current output:

```
{'name': 'John', 'template': <FoobarEnum.FIRST: 'foobar'>}
```

Goal:

```
{'name': 'John', 'template': 'foobar'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't be done with standard library except maybe by some metaclass enum hack I'm not aware of. `Enum.name` and `Enum.value` are builtin and not supposed to be changed.

The approach of using the dataclass `default_factory` isn't going to work either. Because `default_factory` is called to produce default values for the dataclass members, not to customize access to members.

You can either have the Enum member or the Enum.value as a dataclass member, and that's what `asdict()` will return.

If you want to keep an Enum member -not just the Enum.value- as a dataclass member, and have a function converting it to dictionary that returns the Enum.value instead of the Enum member, the correct way to do it is implementing your own method to return the dataclass as a dictionary.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


class FoobarEnum(Enum):
    FIRST = "foobar"
    SECOND = "baz"


@dataclass
class Foobar:
    name: str
    template: FoobarEnum

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'template': self.template.value
        }


# Testing.
print(Foobar(name="John", template=FoobarEnum.FIRST).as_dict())
# {'name': 'John', 'template': 'foobar'}
```

Comment: This approach won't work if you have the instance of your Foobar dataclass as a nested instance of another dataclass. In this case you'll need to make conversation manually and call your custom `as_dict` method on all of your entities. You can use `dict_factory` keyword argument which does exactly what yo need - https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict. With this approach you can call `asdict` on you top entity and it will convert it and all its nested entities nice and easy. See my answer below with the code.

Answer (score 26):

Actually you can do it. **asdict** has keyword argument [dict_factory](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) which allows you to handle your data there:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from enum import Enum


@dataclass
class Foobar:
  name: str
  template: "FoobarEnum"


class FoobarEnum(Enum):
  FIRST = "foobar"
  SECOND = "baz"


def custom_asdict_factory(data):

    def convert_value(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Enum):
            return obj.value
        return obj

    return dict((k, convert_value(v)) for k, v in data)


foobar = Foobar(name="John", template=FoobarEnum.FIRST)

print(asdict(foobar, dict_factory=custom_asdict_factory))
# {'name': 'John', 'template': 'foobar'}
```

Comment: While correct, this is such a counter productive way of handling it. The dataclass should control its asdict() output, not the user.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue where I needed to serialize my dataclass object to JSON and solved it by adding `str` as the first class FoobarEnum inherits from:

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from enum import Enum


@dataclass
class Foobar:
  name: str
  template: "FoobarEnum"


class FoobarEnum(str, Enum):
  FIRST = "foobar"
  SECOND = "baz"


foobar = Foobar(name="John", template=FoobarEnum.FIRST)

print(json.dumps(asdict(foobar)))
```

It doesn't change the behavior of `asdict`, but I can serialize the object now.

Reference: [Serialising an Enum member to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481852/serialising-an-enum-member-to-json)

Comment: Perfect solution! The json.dumps is really needed for it to work.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Thanks. I also use **SomeEnum(str, Enum)**.    
Also, in python 3.11 there are a few builtin Enum classes for that - https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum

Comment: smart and not overcomplicated.

Answer (score 10):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from enum import Enum


class FoobarEnum(Enum):
    FIRST = "foobar"
    SECOND = "baz"


@dataclass
class Foobar:
    name: str
    template: FoobarEnum


def my_dict(data):

    return {
        field: value.value if isinstance(value, Enum) else value
        for field, value in data
    }


foobar = Foobar(name="John", template=FoobarEnum.FIRST)

data = {'name': 'John', 'template': 'foobar'}

assert asdict(foobar, dict_factory=my_dict) == data
```

Comment: Sorry. Missed it. I was in a rush writing the comments. I wanted to write it yesterday but did it only today, so technically you was the first. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the `__deepcopy__` method to achieve what you want:

```
class FoobarEnum(Enum):
  FIRST = "foobar"
  SECOND = "baz"

  def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
      return self.value
```

The `asdict` function handles dataclasses, tuples, lists and dicts. In case of any other type it calls:

`copy.deepcopy(obj)`

Overriding `__deepcopy__` like this is probably not the best idea though.

Comment: It would work but it's not a good idea. You'll have a string instead of Enum in case you need to make an actually `deepcopy` somewhere in your business logic. `asdict` has a keyword argument `dict_factory` which is designed specifically for this https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict. See my answer with the code.

Answer (score 3):

Add `__post_init__` like below.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from enum import Enum
from typing import Union


@dataclass
class Foobar:
    name:str
    template: Union["FoobarEnum", str]
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.template = self.template.value

class FoobarEnum(Enum):
    FIRST = "foobar"
    SECOND = "baz"

foobar = Foobar(name="John", template=FoobarEnum.FIRST)
print(asdict(foobar))
```

Depending on the usecase, you can inherit from both `str` and `Enum` or have a init only field.

Comment: This isn't a good idea. In case if you need an Enum you need an Enum and not string. You can do your Enum conversion in a custom `dict_factory` which is a keyword argument of `asdict` function - https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict. See my answer with code example.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
import json

def dumps(object):
    def default(o):
        if isinstance(o, Enum):
            # use enum value when JSON deserialize the enum
            return o.__dict__['_value_'] 
        else:
            return o.__dict__
    return json.dumps(object, default=default)

print(json.dumps(YOUR_OBJECT_CONTAINS_ENUMS, default=default))
```

Comment: You can do exactly the same approach with `dict_factory` - a keyword argument of `asdict` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict. It does literally the same and you don't need to convert your dataclesses to JSON and back. Please see my answer with code example.