# Serialize to JSON enum from python

Tags: python, json

I have a query that expects an enum of FileType to be passed on.

```
{
    item(itemId: 123){
    page(limit: 5, filters: {fileType: PDF}) {
      row{
        id
        fileName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The fileType filter PDF is expected to be a FileType enum. Below are the enum values.

```
CSV
PDF
EXCEL
DOC
DOCX
PPT
PPTX
PNG
JPG
TIFF
UNKNOWN
```

I have created an enum and am passing the value into my query below (Python 3.8.5):

```
class FileType(str, Enum):
    CSV = 'CSV'
    PDF = 'PDF'
    EXCEL = 'EXCEL'
    DOC = 'DOC'
    DOCX = 'DOCX'
    PPT = 'PPT'
    PPTX = 'PPTX'
    PNG = 'PNG'
    JPG = 'JPG'
    TIFF = 'TIFF'
    UNKNOWN = 'UNKNOWN'


vars = {
           "itemId": itemId,
           "limit": limit,
           "filters": {
               "fileType": json.dump(FileType.DOC)
           }
       }
```

When my code is run FileType.DOC is converted to "DOC" when I expect it to be DOC in the query like the example. How would I go about doing this?

I referenced the solutions in [Serialising an Enum member to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481852/serialising-an-enum-member-to-json) but none of the would work for me.

Comment: The block at the top of your post is not valid JSON.

Comment: You're right, it's part of a GraphQL query. I'm having trouble converting to valid JSON for the {fileType: PDF} part. Everything I try produces something like {fileType: "PDF"} instead.