# Using eval() while using json data

Tags: python, eval

I am storing settings in json file > loading it > using eval to evaluate the stringified data.

However I am sure eval is **not** the best way to do it.

I would like to know if there is any better way to implement it without using eval.
Any pointer will be a great help.

Below is what I have got now.

Store the settings - `decision_settings.json`

```json
{
    "DecisionModelConfig": {   
        "model_type": "ModelType.RULE_BASED",
        "model_path": "DECISION_MODEL_PATH"
    }
}
```

Load the settings - `abc.py`

```py
with open("decision_settings.json", encoding="utf-8") as settings:
    decision_settings = json.load(settings)
```

Use eval to evaluate the `stringified` input as read from json file

```py
from abc.settings import decision_settings
from abc_pqr import ModelType
from abc_xyz import DECISION_MODEL_PATH

class DecisionModelConfig(BaseModel):
    model_type: ModelType = eval(decision_settings["DecisionModelConfig"]["model_type"])
    model_path: Path = eval(pipeline_decision_settings["DecisionModelConfig"]["model_path"])
```

```py
class ModelType(str, Enum):
    RULE_BASED = "rule based"
    MACHINE_LEARNING = "machine learning"
```

```
DECISION_MODEL_PATH = PROJECT_DIR / "models" / "whatever.json"
```

-- EDIT --

This is what we intend to have:

```py
class DecisionModelConfig(BaseModel):
    model_type: ModelType = ModelType.RULE_BASED
    model_path: Path = DECISION_MODEL_PATH
```

This is what we get if we directly use the dict keys(without eval on it) - we get the deserialized data in form of string

```py
class DecisionModelConfig(BaseModel):
    model_type: ModelType = "ModelType.RULE_BASED"
    model_path: Path = "DECISION_MODEL_PATH"
```

Using eval however evaluates the string and we are good.

Comment: Do you need arbitrary Python expressions in your data? If your need is for serializing enum values only, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481852/serialising-an-enum-member-to-json

Comment: @TugrulAtes It's not only for enum. It can have any python expressions.

Comment: In the code you're showing us, you're evaluating a string and getting back the identical string.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks for your time. I have added an edit to show what we intend to get, and what we get if we directly use the dict keys(without eval on it).

Comment: Does it need to be json? You may have a look at "Constructors, representers, resolvers" in the yaml documentation, see https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation